# Linux sever--a "^C" appear behind $ after choosing anything with mouse

Tags: c, linux, mouse, server

I have stage server which I use it with Xmanager. In the stage sever,after whatever I choose using the mouse,a "^C" will appear automatically after $.For example ,I choose "system/" with mouse,and a "^C" soon appears in the command line.

It never happened before until yesterday I tried "Shift+Ctrl+V" which means "copy" after I choosing the command line which I wanted to copy, but it didn't work although I tried several times.And then the problem I described existed.

It's really confusing,and I don't whether "^C" has any bad effect.

How to resolve this problem?Anyone knows why it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason causing this problem is that I opened youdao dictionary simultaneously with its function of catching words on the screen on. Just close it and the problem won't happen again. I don't know why maybe it has something to do with the software's compatibility.